# How to clear text from all text boxes of an XLS file, without removing the boxes?

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

How to clear text from all text boxes of an XLS file, without removing the boxes?

Thank you!

Comment: Please show your code attempts.

Answer (score 0):

please refer this code

```
Sub TextBoxClear()
    For Shts = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        Sheets(Shts).Select
        For TextCnt = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
            ActiveSheet.Shapes(TextCnt).Select
            Selection.Characters.Text = " "
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You should be able to save 2 lines by using `For TextCnt = 1 To Sheets(Shts).Shapes.Count` and `Sheets(Shts).Shapes(TextCnt).Characters.Text = ""`